# Get category id by product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, foreach, woocommerce

What I want to do is make a foreach loop to get all products and from those products I want to get their category id. This so I can later check for certain categories.

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_catagory_id .= $item['catagory_id']; //in between these brackets I need a value that gives me the catagory id.
}

//Some validation here if one of the catagorie_id's was found.
//I can build this. It's not part of the question
```

After some comments, this is where I'm stranded:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    var_dump($product_id);
    $terms = get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'term_id' );
    var_dump($terms);
}
```

This results in the following:

```
string(2) "79"
object(WP_Error)#9148 (2) {
    ["errors"]=>
        array(1) {
        ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>
            array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(19) "Ongeldige taxonomie" //invalid taxonomy
            }
        }
    ["error_data"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
}
```

So the product ID is read perfectly, I can work with that but the category isn't returned properly.

Comment: put `var_dump($item); exit;` in your loop and show us the result

Comment: That doesn't seem to work it gives me `Unable to fix malformed JSON` in the console

Comment: My bad, removing the exit and logging the output gave me the results i needed. Sadly nothing related to catagory or catagory id

Comment: I do have a product Id that may help out a bit..

Comment: use `$item['product_id']` to get the terms..

Comment: I have updated my question with my current state

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
$terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $cat_id = $term->id;
}
```

Try `var_dump($terms);` to rightly analyse how to get category id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you edit `$term->id` to `$tem->term_id` you get the int of the catagory ID. var_dump() wil return `int(x)` where x is the ID